# xcode library file's header not found inside react native plugin

Tags: xcode, react-native, plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm  developing a ios app with use of react native npm plugin and pod files

I have installed pod package using "pod 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore'" and also installed plugin and manually configure the project to the application
My problem is installed ios application of the plugin requires IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore as the header

I have looked into several suggestions related to the topic but could resolve it yet
Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming you're working on a React Native project - which plugin did you install ? 
What is the exact error message you see ?
Have you installed the IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation pod ?

Comment: @Srik Yes I am working on a react native project and I have installed both  IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation and IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore using pods. I am using custom made bridge plugin called react-native-tb that made my self  Error is ios header file (IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore.h) not found in plugin's ios header file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find a solution 
I have added "use_frameworks!" on top of the plugin's pod file and it worked fine